# Unable to mount second hard drive

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a machine with two hard drives. One hard drive is dual-boot, and has both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 installed. The other hard drive is reserved for storage. Until recently, this storage hard drive was accessible from both the Windows and Ubuntu partitions. To do this in Ubuntu, I would open Nautilus and then on the left, there are three items under `Devices`, which are: `250 GB Volume`, `Storage`, and `Computer`. Clicking on `Storage` used to give me access to this second hard drive.

However, for some unknown reason, recently I have been receiving the following error message when I try to click on `Storage`:

```
Unable to access “Storage”

Error mounting /dev/sdb5 at /media/karnivaurus/Storage: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb5" "/media/karnivaurus/Storage"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Please could somebody explain this message to me? I have tried booting into Windows and shutting down fully as suggested, but this did not help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have fast startup checked in the windows control under power options and then system setting, you want to uncheck it.

The reason Ubuntu wont mount it as it is in hibernated state and any file you copy to windows partition might not exist when you boot to windows. This is a security feature in Ubuntu. Unchecking it should do the job.

I have had to run the `ntfsfix` command after unchecking it, you can try it if unchecking doesnt work